# is there a way to style links like aristo buttons?

Tags: css, button, hyperlink

Is there a way - or anyone knows if someone already made this available - a way to style links in the form of buttons in the aristo style?

http://aristocss.com/

Using this CSS -reform a regular link to the style of a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can more than likely copy all the CSS for those buttons and just use it on a link. In fact you'd probably be able to rip out a bunch of reset stuff as buttons often have all sorts of browser defaults which a link doesn't have.

So change:

```
button {
    // Cut
}
```

to:

```
a {
    // Paste
}
```

Hope that helps :)

(The css you need by the way starts right at the top of this file: http://aristocss.com/css/aristo.css)

Comment: seems aristo has some specific stuff and isn't that easy to style but ill look into it later

Answer (score 1):

Sure - just grab the CSS they're already using, change it from `button` to `a.btn`, add `display:block`, give your link a class of "btn" and you're all set.